# Laravel - pivot attach multiple using nested loop. duplicating user_id

Tags: laravel, eloquent, nested, pivot, laravel-8

here is my problem the user_id is duplicating other user_id is not applying or detaching using nested loop, i think the problem is in my **ProjectController** i will show the other photos for specific to describe my problem.

when selecting two projects assigning to single user1 its working fine. its not duplicating ,

like in this phot:[image]

but when im trying to assign different projects and users it's duplicating the user1.. the user2 not attaching on other project[image]

same as here when im assigning a single project to two or multiple users its not attaching only user 1, user 2 not working[image]

this is my blade file. im using name[] and project[]

```
 <form method="POST" class="mx-8 space-x-4" action="{{ route('home.create') }}">
                    @csrf
                    @method('POST')
                    <div class="flex space-x-4">
                    <div class="inline-block relative w-64 mb-2">
                        <label for="" class="mb-5 text-lg">Project</label>
                        <select  name="project[]" class="p-2 block appearance-none bg-white border border-gray-400 hover:border-gray-500 px-4 py-2 pr-8 rounded shadow leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                          @foreach ($projects as $project)
                          <option value="{{ $project->id }}">{{ $project->name }}</option>
                          @endforeach
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inline-block relative w-64 mb-2">
                        <label for="" class="mb-5 text-lg">Name</label>
                        <select name="user[]" class="p-2 block appearance-none bg-white border border-gray-400 hover:border-gray-500 px-4 py-2 pr-8 rounded shadow leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                          @foreach ($users as $user)
                          <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                          @endforeach
                    </select>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="flex space-x-4">
                        <div class="inline-block relative w-64 mb-2">
                            <select  name="project[]" class="p-2 block appearance-none bg-white border border-gray-400 hover:border-gray-500 px-4 py-2 pr-8 rounded shadow leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                              @foreach ($projects as $project)
                              <option value="{{ $project->id }}">{{ $project->name }}</option>
                              @endforeach
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inline-block relative w-64 mb-2">
                            <select name="user[]" class="p-2 block appearance-none bg-white border border-gray-400 hover:border-gray-500 px-4 py-2 pr-8 rounded shadow leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline">
                              @foreach ($users as $user)
                              <option value="{{ $user->id }}">{{ $user->name }}</option>
                              @endforeach
                        </select>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                 <button type="submit" class="bg-green-300 border border-gray-300 p-3">Submit</button>
   </form>
```

this is my **Model Project**

```
class Project extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = ['name'];

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
```

this is my migration **project_user**

```
   public function up()
    {
        if (!Schema::hasTable('project_user')) {
        Schema::create('project_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
           $table->foreignId('project_id')->constrained()->onDelete();
           $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete();
        });

        };
    }
```

this is my **ProjectController** i think my code is wrong for making nested attach to my pivot table that's why when im trying to assign other user_id to other project or single its duplicating

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    foreach($request->input('project') as $project){
        $list=[];
        $projects = Project::find($project);
        foreach($request->input('user') as $user){
         $users = User::find($user);
         $list[$projects->id] = ['user_id'=>$users->id];
        }
     $projects->users()->attach($list);        
    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Successful created!');
}
```

please help to solve this problem, i tried many times but i can't still solve it

Comment: Your code for the create method seems to have 3 open curly brackets (**{**) but only two closing (**}**) . Please rewrite it to make it more understandable.

Comment: sorry i missed that line, thanks for reminding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the create method. Through the form you send two arrays. To know which user you must add to the project you must consult the index of the arrays, so that you must assign the user of users[i] to the project of projects[i]

Another mistake is that the attach method must be used on a model object and you can pass it an id or an array of ids. However you are trying to attach to a project an associative array [project_id => user_id].

I have also renamed some variables to better fit what they represent

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    foreach($request->input('project') as $index => $project_id){
        $project = Project::find($project_id);
        $project->users()->attach($request->input('user')[$index]);     
     }    

    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Successful created!');
}
```

Comment: thank you for explaning well. i understood now what's my mistake

Comment: may i ask something how did worked with input('user')[$index]; im still confused when i tried foreach($request->input('project') as $index => $project_id){} but im trying to return or vardump, dd the $index key it returning 0? how it's possible to get that key when its returning 0 and appying to input('user')[$index];?? thank you in advanced when you notice my comment

Comment: input('user') is an array, so if $index==0, when you do input('user')[$index] then you are accesing to the first position in the array, wich contains a user_id.  
In the first loop iteration we are attaching the user specified at input('user')[0] to the project specified at input('project ')[0], the next loop iteration we will be attaching the user in input('user')[1] with the project in input('project ')[1], and so on for the next iterations.

Comment: aight thanks i got it now. thank you for sharing your knowledge